# merging tuples in python to create a tuple of tuples

Tags: python

So say I want to loop through a List of tuples and extract two mins each time, merge them, then insert them back into the list until I ended up with one giant tuple. This would in turn be a tuple of tuples. So it would look something like this.

```
   for currentValue in range(len(tupleList) - 1):
        t1 = ExtractMin(tupleList)
        #buildHeap(tupleList)
        t2 = ExtractMin(tupleList)
        #buildHeap(tupleList)
        #need to merge but i'm not sure how to go about it
        mergedTuple = t1 + t2
        tupleList.append(tuple(mergedTuple))
```

Is there a best practice in python to merge tuples for a situation like this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of inputs and outputs?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using lists `[]` rather than tuples `()`.  Lists are intended to be flexible in size, where tuples are intended to records of fixed structure.  Then `mergedList = l1 + l2`.

Comment: @JoshuaR. There is a way bigger scale that requires me to use tuples. I would normally use a list. That's why I asked the question. I guess I could convert it to a list then back to a tuple but i was thinking there was a better way

Comment: How does `ExtractMin` choose a minimum tuple? It might be possible to just sort the list on some criteria, then merge them in a single pass with something like `[x for y in tupleList for x in y]`. (Also, `mergedTuple` is already a tuple; there's no need to call `tuple` again. `tupleList.append(mergedTuple)`.)

Comment: mergedTuple = t1 + (t2,)
This seems to be working i'll add a solution after I test some more.